# Generate DOF (not depth) map from blender

Tags: depth-of-field, depth-map

I've found several ways to generate depth map from blender, but if my focus point is not the closest one, or the width of my focus area is bigger, I can't really use them to add depth of field later, in post. Can you recommend a method for the new version of blender, to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to change the position of the camera to where you want the focus point to be then bake the map and move the camera somewhere else?

Comment: I guess - unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to answer the question, but I hope there is a more direct and/or simple solution - for animaions for example, where the camera, and the focus point are moving frame by frame.

Comment: use this https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/defocus.html

Comment: "Z-buffer input, but could also be a (grayscale) image used as a mask, or a single value input." 
This grayscale image what I need, as I do the post in photoshop. I render with eevee, and I don't have Z output on the render node. Is it normal?